# Docker container, how to use host proxy

Tags: proxy, docker

Because I'm in China it is nearly impossible to use Docker Hub, Git, GitHub, npm and loads of other tools without a VPN.

I finally found how to have the Docker daemon [use a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438861/1641941) (share VPN in the VPN client software on the host is the proxy server).

But as soon as I run the container I'm behind the firewall again and the container is not using the host proxy. This would make it impossible to get anything from GitHub, use npm, Bower and lots of other things.

How can I force the container to use the host proxy?

Comment: something similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/662297/transparent-proxying-a-single-docker-container-to-another-docker-container might be worth the try (playing with iptables). See also https://github.com/silarsis/docker-proxy/

Comment: @Thomasleveil I think I can use docker run -it --net host centos:latest as used in this site: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/17/transparent-squid-proxy-docker then set env variables to use the proxy on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the proxy in `/etc/default/docker`.

I also had to unset the proxy in the environment variables:

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: That may work, I used `--net host` for now. If running on a mac using VirtualBox it gets a bit more complicated (container to host (=boot2docker) to host (=mac))

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could set a proxy maybe in the config but to what ip? In the container I have no idea what the ip of the host is. When I docker run a container I can use `--net host` (not if I want to link another container because that option is not valid then) but when I do docker build with a docker file there is no --net host option. Just to make it clear; I would like the container to use a proxy that the host is serving but I don't know how to connect from the container to the host. All documentation states connecting host to container but not the other way.

Comment: I find that 172.17.42.1 points to the host so setting proxy to http://172.17.42.1:8080 and setting the firewall correctly on my host solves it.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use `--network=host` to isolate your Docker from the host's network, you need to make the host network available inside Docker.

When running docker use: (Linux, Docker version > 20.10)

`--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway`

Say your proxy is running on port `3128`, inside your docker container you need to set

`http_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128`

Also make sure that you set `Gateway yes` in `/etc/cntlm.conf` if that's the proxy you're using.

Answer (score 0):

do this in dockerfile.

```
ENV https_proxy="https://192.168.3.22:25526"
ENV http_proxy="http://192.168.3.22:25526"
```

the addr should be your proxy addr.